# Proof of the Dunford-Pettis theorem in the context of probability spaces

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, measure-theory, alternative-proof

I'd like to know if there's a proof of the Dunford-Pettis theorem without using relatively advanced theorems of functional analysis such as Eberlein–Smulian Theorem. Since I'm only interested in probability spaces, I'd like a proof that only uses standard measure theory theorems which you can find, for instance, in "[Measure and Integration](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf)" (by Salamon) and "[Advanced Probability](https://noter.math.ku.dk/vidsand12.pdf)" (by Sokol and Rønn-Nielsen).

Below is the version of the Dunford-Pettis theorem that I'm interest in.

**Dunford-Pettis theorem:** Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq L^1(\mathbb{P})$ be a collection of integrable random variables. Then the following propositions are equivalent:

1. Every sequence of $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a further subsequence $\{X_{n_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that exists $X\in L^1(\mathbb{P})$ with $\mathbb{E}[X_{n_k}Y]\to \mathbb{E}[XY]$ as $k\to \infty$ for all bounded random variables $Y$.
2. $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}[|X_n|]<\infty$ and for all $\varepsilon >0$ there's $\delta >0$ such that for all $E\in \Sigma $ with $\mathbb{P}(E)<\delta $ we have $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{1}_{E}|X_n|]<\varepsilon $

---

If you know a reference that contains a proof of the previous theorem which avoids relatively advanced theorems of functional analysis, please tell me. Also, if you know how to prove it, then please give me some hints because I don't know where I should start to prove that theorem.

---

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look at the first volume of *Probabilités et Potentiel* (translated as *Probability and Potentials*) by C. Dellacherie and P.-A. Meyer; Dunford-Pettis is discussed in II.25.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately the book also uses the Eberlein–Smulian Theorem to prove that equivalence!

Comment: But the give a short measure-theoretic proof of a version of E-S that is sufficient for their purposes.

Comment: @JohnDawkins : It seems that the problem with this approach is that the implication (1)$\implies$(2) in Theorem 25-II of Dellacherie--Meyer -- approximately corresponding to the implication 2$\implies$1 in the OP -- would only give a weakly convergent subnet, rather than a subsequence, of the sequence $(X_n)$.

Comment: One needs the additional information that weakly compact sets in separable Banach spaces (like the closed linear span of the $X_n$) are metrisable; therefore one actually can extract a weakly convergent subsequence.

Comment: @DirkWerner : Yes, this would complete the proof.

Comment: Well, this does complete the proof since the metrisability of weakly compact sets in separable spaces is a well-known fact (showing the easy half of Eberlein-Shmulyan).

Comment: @DirkWerner : Yes, I should have said that this does complete the proof.